# Determine whether function is 1 to 1: $f(x) = x^2-2x$

Tags: calculus

I am following these steps:

1) Write $y= f(x)$

2) Solve this equation for $x$ in terms of $y$ (if possible).

3) To express $f^{-1}$ as a function of $x$, interchange $x$ and $y$.

The resulting equation is $y=f^{-1}(x)$

My work:

$f(x) = x^2 - 2x$

$y = x^2 -2x $

$x= y^2-2y$

$x= y(y-2)$ This is where I am stuck?

Comment: What is the domain of your function?

Comment: put your math equation in between $ $

Comment: Also, how did you get from "$y=x^2 - 2x$" to "$x=2y^2-2y$"? This line is not correct.

Comment: The aim is to find if the function is one to one.

Comment: I am saying that if you want to solve $y=x^2-2x$ to find x as a function of $Y$, this step is not mathematically valid (and in particular will not get you to the solution).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll eventually depend on the domain of your function, but assuming it is $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (the function is defined on the whole set of reals), then, observe that $f(x)=x(x-2)$. This means that $f(0)=0$ *and* $f(2)=0$. But both $0$ and $2$ belong to the domain of the function... Can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method to solve this problem. Recall the definition

> Definition: $f$ is 1-1 on $A$ if whenever $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2\in A$ then $x_1=x_2$.

For our function, $f(x) = x^2-2x$, we find that (using $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$)

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2) \iff (x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2-2) = 0$$

and since $x_2 = 2-x_1$ is a solution it follows that $f$ is not 1-1 on $\mathbb{R}$.

If we restrict ourselves to an interval $A$ not containing $x=1$ (except possibly on the boundary) then the function is 1-1 on this interval because the two $x$ values mentioned above lies symmetric around $x=1$ so such intervals can only have one of them in it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is so solve the quadratic equation $y^2-2y-x=0$ by the quadratic formula,
with $a=1$, $b=-2$, and $c=x$.

Comment: So do I follow the rules I posted?

Answer (score 0):

$$y = x^2 -2x = (x-1)^2 -1$$
$$ \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 = y+1$$
$$\Rightarrow x = 1\pm \sqrt{y+1}$$
Hence, it is NOT one to one. 
For example, let $y=3$. Clearly, $x$ can take two values ($3$ or $-1$).

Comment: There seems to be an additional $1$ that went missing between the second-to-last and last lines. Also, working with implications instead of equivalences does not actually (from a logical point of view) prove what you claim after the "Hence." (you prove that any solution must be one of the two values, not that the two values are solutions). Using logical symbols is often misleading.

Answer (score 0):

remember you are trying to solve for $y$ in the quadratic equation $$y^2 - 2y - x = 0.\tag 1$$  and you are assuming that $x$ is known. if you match the equation with your regular quadratic $$ay^2 + by + c = 0,$$  then the match is $$a = 1, b = -2, c = x. $$ the quadratic formula gives you $$y = \frac{2\pm\sqrt{4 + 4x}}2 = 1\pm \sqrt{1+x}$$ you will have to choose one of the signs for your inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative $f'(x)=(2x-2)$ is both positive and negative (in different regions of course) then f is also both increasing and decreasing. By continuity, there is an interval on which the function f is not 1-to-1